# What's the complete structure of a figure handle object?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

Mathworks has done it again:  my ancient R2012 (as bestowed by my company) returns a nice set of `double`s identifying the figure window numbers  in response to

```
currhandles=findall(0,'type','figure');
```

Now I got a fellow remotely IM-ing me 'cause the code I gave him fails under R2015 because `findall` now returns a structure for the figure handle.   I can't play w/ his system (no RDC) and the mathworks documentation pages don't appear to specify the elements of the figure handle structure.   In particular, I'd like to know if I can still retrieve the figure window number.  Anyone know?

Comment: See: [Graphics Handles Are Now Objects, Not Doubles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html). [Loren's blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/10/14/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-2-using-graphics-objects/) on the topic expands on this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course.

```
currhandles(:).Number
```

will return all numbers as a comma-separated list.

Or specify a number you want:

```
currhandles(1).Number
```

The order appears to be the inverse order of initialization.

---

Alternatively you can define two anonymous functions to get an array directly:

```
figure(1); figure(2); figure(42);

getNumbers = @(x) [x.Number];
getFigureNumbers = @() getNumbers([findall(0,'type','figure')]);

getFigureNumbers()
```

---

```
ans =

    42     2     1
```

Comment: Child order is generally related to initialization order.